# Terraform resets credentials when importing existing RDS db resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-import

We have a bunch of existing resources on AWS that we want to import under terraform managment. One of these resources is an RDS db. So we wrote something like this :

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
    engine   = "postgres"
    username = var.rds_username 
    password = var.rds_password
    # other stuff...
}

variable "rds_username" {
    type    = string 
    default = "master_username"
}

variable "rds_password" {
    type      = string 
    default   = "master_password"
    sensitive = true  
}
```

Note these are the *existing* master credentials. That's important. Then we did this:

```
terraform import aws_db_instance.db db-identifier
```

And then tried `terraform plan` a few times, tweaking the code to fit the existing resource until finally, `terraform plan` indicated there were no changes to be made (which was the goal).

However, once we ran `terraform apply`, it reset the master credentials of the DB instance. Worse, other resources that had previously connected to that DB using these exact credentials suddenly can't anymore.

Why is this happening? Is terraform encrypting the password behind the scenes and not telling me? Why can't other services connect to the DB using the same credentials? Is there any way to import an RDS instance without resetting credentials?

Comment: Is it for this specific rds instance? What if you create a dummy new instance and the import it?

Comment: @Marcin It's a specific RDS instance, but I recreated the issue with a new dummy instance so I can confirm this is a consistent behaviour. My suspicion is that terraform encrypts passwords in some form in the background but I can't confirm it and there's nothing in the documentation about it

Comment: Its not encrypted, it is actually stored in plain text in your state file, thus it is super un-safe.

Comment: Just basic questions: are you using latest TF and aws provider? Also are you sure that password and username are absolutely correct? You can also try to `ignore_changes` for the password and username.

Comment: @Marcin isn't `sensitive = true` supposed to handle that? Also we just set it up like this to import the resource, this isn't a long term security solution anyway. We are using the latest versions yes, we are sure the username & password are correct we have tried and tested it multiple times. I haven't tried `ignore_changes` but that's not really a solution is it? It's just avoiding the issue, as we might want to control those down the line as well

Comment: `sensitive = true` is not for state file, but just what TF outputs into console. I don't know what else could be wrong. Could be bug in TF.

Comment: @Marcin yeah we don't know what else to do now, if it's a bug or some sort of expected behavior. I've asked about it in the TF forums as well, maybe someone there will know

Comment: If the plan didn't include any proposed actions then applying it should've done nothing... Terraform only asks a provider to apply a change if there was a change to apply. Sounds like something else was going on here but I'm not sure what... 

Comment: @MartinAtkins I don't know what else could go wrong. As I've said in a previous comment, I tested this in a clean environment with a completely new db. You can replicate it yourself. My only solution right now is to just avoid providing username & pass, as tf doesn't actually need to manage that at the moment but it's not really a long term solution